# React component loading twice with redux

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get the state from redux store but whenever I access my redux action my component is loaded twice
By loading route manually first time it returns the two objects,one object of empty state and other object of updated state
However when I am switching between routes it returns the new state but twice each time or two objects of same state.

This causes undefined error on loading component specially when manually loading the route , when I am accessing any state property,

```
Redux action
export function getRelationshipStatus() {
    let headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`
    }
    return dispatch => {
        axios.get('http://localhost/relation/api/get-relationship-status', { headers })
        .then(  response => dispatch({type:ActionTypes.GET_RELATIONSHIP_STATUS,payload:response.data}))
    }
};
```

Reducer

```
import React from 'react'
import {GET_RELATIONSHIP_STATUS} from  '../actions/action-types'
const initialState={
    profile:{},
}
export default function (state=initialState,action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_RELATIONSHIP_STATUS:
        console.log(action.payload);
        return {...state,profile:action.payload}
        break;
        default:
        return state
    }
}
```

Actual Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {getRelationshipStatus} from '../../store/actions'
 class People extends Component {
     constructor(props){
         super(props)
     }
      componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getRelationshipStatus()
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.profile)

        return (
            <div>


            </div>
        )
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        profile: state.profile,
    }
}
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { getRelationshipStatus }
)(People);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey it's total natural behaviour of react-redux loading twice.

Even i can explain you but that's not question

I'm sure this behaviour is not problem 
By the way what is error name?

Comment: Ok but it also returns 'undefined' on first reload that causes error in accessing the state in component

Comment: Please show error message on that basis i can try to help you